# delete specific rows from csv using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file in the format shown below:[image]

I have written the following code that reads the file and randomly deletes the rows that have steering value as 0. I want to keep just 10% of the rows that have steering value as 0.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names = ["center", "left", "right", "steering", "throttle", 'break', 'speed'])
df = df.drop(df.query('steering==0').sample(frac=0.90).index)
```

However, I get the following error:

> df = df.drop(df.query('steering==0').sample(frac=0.90).index)
>
> locs = rs.choice(axis_length, size=n, replace=replace, p=weights)
>
> File "mtrand.pyx", line 1104, in mtrand.RandomState.choice
>   (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:17062)
>
> ValueError: a must be greater than 0

Can you guys help me?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Your code is working fine for me. It looks like your Numpy module is broken...

Comment: I was able to remove the error by converting the column into integer. But even after that, the code just runs without removing the rows.

Comment: I've added an answer with a demo based on @andrew_reece's sample DF. PS don't forget to upvote [andrew_reece's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43603391/5741205) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sample DataFrame [built with @andrew_reece's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43603391/5741205)

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
           center         left         right  steering  throttle  brake
0   center_54.jpg  left_75.jpg  right_39.jpg         1         0      0
1   center_20.jpg  left_81.jpg  right_49.jpg         3         1      1
2   center_34.jpg  left_96.jpg  right_11.jpg         0         4      2
3   center_98.jpg  left_87.jpg  right_34.jpg         0         0      0
4   center_67.jpg  left_12.jpg  right_28.jpg         1         1      0
5   center_11.jpg  left_25.jpg  right_94.jpg         2         1      0
6   center_66.jpg  left_27.jpg  right_52.jpg         1         3      3
7   center_18.jpg  left_50.jpg  right_17.jpg         0         0      4
8   center_60.jpg  left_25.jpg  right_28.jpg         2         4      1
9   center_98.jpg  left_97.jpg  right_55.jpg         3         3      0
..            ...          ...           ...       ...       ...    ...
90  center_31.jpg  left_90.jpg  right_43.jpg         0         1      0
91  center_29.jpg   left_7.jpg  right_30.jpg         3         0      0
92  center_37.jpg  left_10.jpg  right_15.jpg         1         0      0
93  center_18.jpg   left_1.jpg  right_83.jpg         3         1      1
94  center_96.jpg  left_20.jpg  right_56.jpg         3         0      0
95  center_37.jpg  left_40.jpg  right_38.jpg         0         3      1
96  center_73.jpg  left_86.jpg  right_71.jpg         0         1      0
97  center_85.jpg  left_31.jpg   right_0.jpg         3         0      4
98  center_34.jpg  left_52.jpg  right_40.jpg         0         0      2
99  center_91.jpg  left_46.jpg  right_17.jpg         0         0      0

[100 rows x 6 columns]

In [10]: df.steering.value_counts()
Out[10]:
0    43    # NOTE: 43 zeros
1    18
2    15
4    12
3    12
Name: steering, dtype: int64

In [11]: df.shape
Out[11]: (100, 6)
```

your solution (unchanged):

```
In [12]: df = df.drop(df.query('steering==0').sample(frac=0.90).index)

In [13]: df.steering.value_counts()
Out[13]:
1    18
2    15
4    12
3    12
0     4        # NOTE: 4 zeros (~10% from 43)
Name: steering, dtype: int64

In [14]: df.shape
Out[14]: (61, 6)
```

**NOTE:** make sure that `steering` column has numeric dtype! If it's a string (object) then you would need to change your code as follows:

```
df = df.drop(df.query('steering=="0"').sample(frac=0.90).index)
#  NOTE:                         ^ ^
```

after that you can save the modified (reduced) DataFrame to CSV:

```
df.to_csv('/path/to/filename.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: So this command doesn't permanently remove the rows from the file, right?

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta, no, it deletes rows from the DataFrame. Then you can save that modified DataFrame to CSV

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-line approach, using `concat()` and `sample()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# first, some sample data

# generate filename fields
positions = ['center','left','right']
N = 100
fnames = ['{}_{}.jpg'.format(loc, np.random.randint(100)) for loc in np.repeat(positions, N)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(fnames).reshape(3,100).T, columns=positions)

# generate numeric fields
values = [0,1,2,3,4]
probas = [.5,.2,.1,.1,.1]
df['steering'] = np.random.choice(values, p=probas, size=N)
df['throttle'] = np.random.choice(values, p=probas, size=N)
df['brake'] = np.random.choice(values, p=probas, size=N)

print(df.shape)
(100,3)
```

The first few rows of sample output:

```
df.head()
           center         left         right  steering  throttle  brake
0   center_72.jpg  left_26.jpg  right_59.jpg         3         3      0
1   center_75.jpg  left_68.jpg  right_26.jpg         0         0      2
2   center_29.jpg   left_8.jpg  right_88.jpg         0         1      0
3   center_22.jpg  left_26.jpg  right_23.jpg         1         0      0
4   center_88.jpg   left_0.jpg  right_56.jpg         4         1      0
5   center_93.jpg  left_18.jpg  right_15.jpg         0         0      0
```

Now drop all but 10% of rows with `steering==0`:

```
newdf = pd.concat([df.loc[df.steering!=0], 
                   df.loc[df.steering==0].sample(frac=0.1)])
```

With the probability weightings I used in this example, you'll see somewhere between 50-60 remaining entries in `newdf`, with about 5 `steering==0` cases remaining.

Comment: I like your data generation code - it's very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Using a mask on `steering` combined with a random number should work:

```
df = df[(df.steering != 0) | (np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.1)]
```

This does generate some extra random values, but it's nice and compact.

Edit: That said, I tried your example code and it worked as well. My guess is the error is coming from the fact that your `df.query()` statement is returning an empty dataframe, which probably means that the `"sample"` column does not contain any zeros, or alternatively that the column is read as strings rather than numeric. Try converting the column to integer before running the above snippet.

Comment: Hey, I tried the code but it doesn't remove the rows.

Comment: See my edit. You will need to convert your column from string to int before running either my solution or yours.

Comment: So I converted the column into integer and ran both the codes, it's not working. I used `df.steering= df.steering.astype(int)` to convert the column into int