# Deleting rows in pandas dataframe whose RGB value is black (0,0,0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv table that looks like this

```
    pixIndex       X       Y    R    G    B
           1       0       0  227  227  227
           2       1       0  237  237  237
           3       2       0   0     0    0
           4       3       0  232  232  232
           5       4       0  233  233  233
...        ...     ...     ...  ...  ...  ...
```

I would like to remove those rows that have black points i.e 0,0,0.

Currently I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("outputdata.txt", header=None, names =["pixIndex","X","Y","R","G","B"] )
print(df)  
df = df.drop(df.query('R==0 & G==0 & B==0'))
print(df)
```

However at the line where I do the df.drop() call, I get an error saying

```
 "pixIndex","X","Y","R","G","B" not found in axis"
```

I have looked at these 2 SO questions but still unable to fix my code.
[delete specific rows from csv using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600066/delete-specific-rows-from-csv-using-pandas)
[pandas: multiple conditions while indexing data frame - unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591174/pandas-multiple-conditions-while-indexing-data-frame-unexpected-behavior)

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Any help is appreciated please. Thank you! :)

Comment: `df[df[['R','G','B']].sum(1).ne(0)]`?

Comment: your query can be used with an `!=`;  `df.query('R!=0 & G!=0 & B!=0')` or with your method you need to call the index for dropping `df.drop(df.query('R==0 & G==0 & B==0').index)`

Comment: @AnuragDabas thanks for the suggestion! this gives the output of all remaining the rows being 0,0,0. I want to remove the rows that have the 0,0,0 :)

Comment: `df=df[df[['R','G','B']].sum(1).ne(0)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any:

```
df[df[['R','G','B']].ne(0).any(1)]
```

With query:

```
df.query('R!=0 & G!=0 & B!=0')
```

With your version of query and df.drop with additional df.index for the drop:

```
df.drop(df.query('R==0 & G==0 & B==0').index)
```